# Select com Json

Tags: javascript, json

Olá, Tudo bem?
Eu estou tentando fazer popular um select com Json que já venha selecionado o item. Eu consegui fazer até a população do select listando todos os modelos de carros só não consegui já trazer ele selecionado. Alguem pode me ajuda?

```
var handlerCarregaMarca = function(){

        var marca = $('#tipo-id').val();
        var marcaid = $('#marca-id').val();

        console.log(marca);
        console.log(marcaid);


        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:'listarMarcas?codigo='+marca,
            dataType: "html",
            async:false,
            success: function (data) {
                // console.log(data);

                var output= '<option value="">Selecione o Tipo do Veiculo</option>';
                var dados = JSON.parse(data);

                $.each(dados, function(i, item){
                    output += '<option value="'+item.marc_id+'""'+item.marc_id == marcaid ? 'selected':''+'">'+item.marc_nome+'</option>'
                });

                $("#marca-veiculo").html(output);
                $("#marca-veiculo").trigger('chosen:updated');
            }
        });

        $(this).val(marca);
```

Esse é o codigo que eu estou utilizando.

Comment: pode colocar um exemplo de retorno do json `data`

Comment: O data retorna assim marc_exibir
:
"1"
marc_foto
:
"Fiat.jpg"
marc_id
:
"1"
marc_nome
:
"Fiat"
marc_tipo
:
"1"

Comment: Eu consigo listar tudo certinho, o que eu não consigo já vim selecionado sabe, eu consigo fazer isso no html mas no json não vai.

Comment: `dataType`, não `data`, como disse o Guilherme Costamilam, está esperando um resultado `HTML`. Troque para `JSON`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cara tem um erro na sua operação lógica.

tente trocar isso:

```
$.each(dados, function(i, item){
  output += '<option value="'+item.marc_id+'""'+item.marc_id == marcaid ? 'selected':''+'">'+item.marc_nome+'</option>'
});
```

por isso:

```
$.each(dados, function(i, item){
  output += "<option value='"+item.marc_id+"' "+((item.marc_id == marcaid) ? 'selected':'')+">"+item.marc_nome+"</option>"
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo.